# How can I save objects as XML files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on my high-school matriculation asp.net project, and I wish to make a website of a bookstore.

I want to create two classes,`Book` and `BookStore`, and save the data created in XML files and not in a database.

How can I save objects as XML files, and how can I load them afterwards?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use XML serialisation. There are tons of examples of how to do this, but here's one link for you to get started:

http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=236